# Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL is not working along with Npgsql package version 4.0.0

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, serilog

In my ASP.Net Core application, a Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL sink works fine along with Npgsql package version lower then 4.0.0, but it does not work along with Npgsql package version 4.0.0.
Along with Npgsql package version 4.0.0 it does not save log events into the database nor throw any exceptions into the SelfLog.

Have you got a same experience? Thanks.

Comment: My application targets NET.Core 2.1.

Comment: See https://github.com/b00ted/serilog-sinks-postgresql/issues/11.